# How to avoid concurrent requests to a lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a  ReportGeneration lambda that takes request from client and adds following entries to a DDB table.

```
Customer ID <hash key>
ReportGenerationRequestID(UUID) <sort key>
ExecutionStartTime
ReportExecutionStatus < workflow status>
```

I have enabled DDB stream trigger on this table and a create entry in this table triggers the report generation workflow. This is a multi-step workflow that takes a while to complete.
Where ReportExecutionStatus is the status of the report processing workflow.
I am supposed to maintain  the history of all report generation requests that a customer has initiated.

Now What I am trying to do is avoid concurrent processing requests by the same customer, so if a report for a customer is already getting generated don’t create another record in DDB ?

Option Considered :

- query ddb for the customerID(consistent read) :
  - From the list see if any entry is either InProgress or Scheduled
- If not then create a new one (consistent write)
- Otherwise return already existing

Issue: If customer clicks in a split second to generate report, two lambdas can be triggered, causing 2 entires in DDB and two parallel workflows can be initiated something that I don’t want.

Can someone recommend what will be the best approach to ensure that there are no concurrent executions (2 worklflows) for the same Report from same customer.
In short when one execution is in progress another one should not start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html) to only create the entry if it doesn't already exist - if you need to check different items, than you can use [DynamoDB Transactions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-dynamodb-transactions/) to check if another item already exists and if not, create your item.

Those would be the ways to do it with DynamoDB, getting a higher consistency.

Another option would be to use SQS FIFO queues. You can group them by the customer ID, then you wouldn't have concurrent processing of messages for the same customer. Additionally with this SQS solution you get all the advantages of using SQS - like automated retry mechanisms or a dead letter queue.

Comment: I always forget about the ConditionExpression. If you know before hand what to check for in your write action condition, then this is better.

Comment: I am not sure how ConditionExpression and Transactions can be utilized for my use case. ConditionExpression essentially operates over a primary key which in my case is Customer ID and ReportGenerationRequestID, since ReportGenerationRequestID is a random number I can not give a specific primary key as that will only return a single record while I want to check all records for a  Customer ID. Also Transactions doesn’t have a query [action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html)  how can I do a getItem to get list of all entries for a customer ?

Comment: when you said "DynamoDB Transactions to check if another item already exists and if not, create your item", In my case another item can exist with a status failed/completed but another item with workflow status sheduled/InProgress should not exist. I hope I am able to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

Limiting the number of concurrent Lambda executions is not possible as far as I know. That is the whole point of AWS Lambda, to easily scale and run multiple Lambdas concurrently.

That said, there is probably a better solution for your problem using a DynamoDB feature called "[Strongly Consistent Reads](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html)"

By default reads to DynamoDB (if you use the AWS SDK) are eventually consistent, causing the behaviour you observed: Two writes to the same table are made but your Lambda only was able to notice one of those writes.

If you use Strongly consistent reads, the documentation states:

> When you request a strongly consistent read, DynamoDB returns a response with the most up-to-date data, reflecting the updates from all prior write operations that were successful.

So your Lambda needs to do a strongly consistent read to your table to check if the customer already has a job running. If there is already a job running the Lambda does not create a new job.